# How can I get a list of the items stored in html 5 local storage from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get a list of the items stored in html 5 local storage from javascript?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

From [HTML5 reference](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html):

> Like other JavaScript objects, you
>   can treat the localStorage object as
>   an associative array. Instead of using
>   the getItem() and setItem() methods,
>   you can simply use square brackets.

```
localStorage.setItem('test', 'testing 1');
localStorage.setItem('test2', 'testing 2');
localStorage.setItem('test3', 'testing 3');

for(var i in localStorage)
{
    console.log(localStorage[i]);
}

//test for firefox 3.6 see if it works
//with this way of iterating it
for(var i=0, len=localStorage.length; i<len; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage[key];
    console.log(key + " => " + value);
}
```

This will output:

```
testing 3
testing 2
testing 1

test3 => testing 3
test2 => testing 2
test => testing 1
```

Here is the [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/4XnpD/)

Comment: Worked for me in chrome, but firefox 3.6 threw the error "TypeError: null has invalid __iterator__ value null"

Comment: @Kyle it works great in firefox 4.  it came out yesterday let me check for 3.6

Comment: @Kyle Even though Firefox supports localStorage, it can be turned off. Check that it is turned on. Go to about:config and check that dom.storage.enabled is set to true.

Comment: yes it's enabled. And when doing `console.debug(localStorage)`, I can see the test variables in it.

Comment: @Kyle can you run the jsfiddle demo and see if you get the same error?

Comment: strange.  i suppose 3.6 doesn't support the first way

Comment: Be aware the first option will also loop over all properties, not just the keys you have added. I modified the first loop too `console.log('key', i, 'val', localStorage[i])` and got :

`"key" "test" "val" "testing 1" 
"key" "test3" "val" "testing 3" 
"key" "test2" "val" "testing 2"
"key" "key" "val" function () 
"key" "getItem" "val" function () 
"key" "setItem" "val" function () 
"key" "removeItem" "val" function () 
"key" "clear" "val" function () 
"key" "length" "val" 3`

Answer (score 32):

localStorage is reference to object window.Storage, so u can use it as each other object:

Get array of items

```
Object.keys(localStorage)
```

Get length

```
Object.keys(localStorage).length
```

Iterate with jquery

```
$.each(localStorage, function(key, value){
   .....
})
```

Comment: jQuery?!  Facepalm.  `Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => console.log(localStorage[key]));`

Comment: Is there a way to get entries for all domains, instead of the one in the current tab?

Answer (score 6):

you can use `Object.assign()`:

```
var data = Object.assign({}, localStorage)
```

Comment: Awesome solution with way less cruft

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
Object.keys(localStorage).map(k => localStorage.getItem(k))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since localStorage is key-value with strings, just serialize it with JSON, and deserialize it when you want to retrieve it.

```
 localStorage.setItem("bar", JSON.stringify([1,2,3]));
 var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");
 JSON.parse(foo);
 // returns [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `localStorage` as a plain object but [it's not reccomended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Basic_concepts).

Here is a safer solution:

```
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    const key = localStorage.key(i);
    const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    console.log({key, value})
}
```